# Mysql ORDER BY using date data row

Tags: php, sql, mysql, sql-order-by

I have a query something like this:

```
SELECT 
 title, desc, date 
FROM 
 tablename 
ORDER BY 
 date ASC, title ASC;
```

Works fine when the data actually has a date. Issue is, date submission is optional, so I sometimes get 0000-00-00 as a date, which has the unfortunate effect of placing all nondated rows on top.

So, I then tried this:

```
SELECT 
 title, desc, date 
FROM 
 tablename 
ORDER BY 
 date DESC, title ASC;
```

Which sort of works, but not really -- all items with dates (non 0000-00-00) get listed in descending order, followed by all items with 0000-00-00.

What I want to do is order by date ASC, title ASC, but only if the date != 0000-00-00, but if date is = 0000-00-00, then just ORDER BY title ASC on those (I think I explained that correctly).

The only ways I can think to do this are non-SQL based (either 2 queries, or, each query just populates an in-memory array, and then I sort using PHP).

Is there a SQL query that can do this?

Comment: Does MySQL not support NULL dates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your 2 query solution is a good one, you can do it all in SQL using the [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html) command.

The first query will be for dates that are non-zero, then UNION in the query for dates that are zero.

Edit: Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl 
   WHERE DATE != '0000-00-00' 
   ORDER BY date ASC 
UNION SELECT * FROM tbl
   WHERE DATE = '0000-00-00'
   ORDER BY title ASC
```

This may not be very useful in this instance, but for complex queries, `UNION` can come in handy.

Comment: This worked when I placed parenthesis around the select blocks like this: ( SELECT * FROM tbl 
   WHERE DATE != '0000-00-00' 
   ORDER BY date ASC )
UNION ( SELECT * FROM tbl
   WHERE DATE = '0000-00-00'
   ORDER BY title ASC )

Comment: Oops, you're right, the UNION technically does things without order mattering, but the parenthesis prevents this, I believe in the reference it does say this.

Answer (score 9):

```
ORDER BY date = '0000-00-00' ASC, date ASC, title ASC
```