# MySQL: ORDER BY with empty date '0000-00-00' as last but the rest ASC

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

In our database, instead of making empty dates `NULL`, they are `'0000-00-00'` (I know, it sucks). How can I order these so that dates that are not `'0000-00-00'` are **first** and ordered `ASC`, and then the empty dates of `'0000-00-00'` come after?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880430/mysql-order-by-using-date-data-row

Comment: Not quite. The answer here is much different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
...
ORDER BY CASE WHEN YourDateColumn = '0000-00-00' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END,
         YourDateColumn
```

Comment: For anyone looking at another answer but also for '0000-00-00' to be the first result for DESC sorting, this is what worked for me:
...
ORDER BY YourDateColumn  = '0000-00-00' DESC, YourDateColumn DESC

Answer (score 5):

Try Below :

```
  SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY (date_column='0000-00-00'), date_column ASC
```

OR

```
select * from your_table
order by if(date_column='0000-00-00',1,0),date_column;
```

Comment: This is a fantastically simple and elegant answer. I have NO clue why this hasn't been upvoted yet. Thanks for your contribution user319198

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CASE WHEN` 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html

```
... ORDER BY (CASE WHEN date = '0000-00-00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASC, otherColumns asc, ...
```

Comment: I think `... ORDER BY (CASE WHEN date = '0000-00-00' THEN ~0 ELSE date END) ASC, otherColumns asc, ...` would work better :)

Comment: No, I used it to put all records with '000-00-00' on the bottom. After that, you can add a `date asc`: `ORDER BY (CASE WHEN date = '0000-00-00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASC, date ASC, ...`

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY (DateColumn = 0)
       , DateColumn
```

Comment: Because `DateColumn = 0` returns a Boolean, which is `0` for false and `1` for true.

Comment: @MarcusAdams: thnx, I sometimes forget to add an explanation.