# mysql ORDER BY with CASE - too slow, faster way?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, case, filesort

Looking at the [various answers for ORDER BY with CASE like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319553/mysql-order-by-with-empty-date-0000-00-00-as-last-but-the-rest-asc), I see that what I am forced to do in this legacy application is likely an expert method; however, it is too slow when the rows are less than trivial (rows of 100,000 or more cause page loads of 10 seconds).

Please note that the original query seeks to solve an apparently common problem where the query analyst needs dates that are empty sorted counter to how they would normally be sorted.  In this case, `datefirstprinted` is to be descending, but all records that are not printed should be populated to the top of the list.

The **Original Query** solves this, but the point of the question is to avoid the `filesort` performance hit that comes with the derived column `notprintedyet`.

> > Original Query

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
  id, daterun, datefirstprinted,
  case datefirstprinted when "0000-00-00 00:00:00" then 1 else 0 end as notprintedyet
FROM
  patientrecords
WHERE
  dateuploaded <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
ORDER BY
  notprintedyet desc,                                 /* ordered via alias */
  datefirstprinted desc
LIMIT 10;
```

**time 1.52s**

---

I found that not sorting on the alias `notprintedyet` saves a bit:

> > Slightly Faster Query

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
  id, daterun, datefirstprinted,
  case datefirstprinted when "0000-00-00 00:00:00" then 1 else 0 end as notprintedyet
FROM
  patientrecords
WHERE
  dateuploaded <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
ORDER BY
  datefirstprinted = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" desc,      /* directly ordered */
  datefirstprinted
LIMIT 10;
```

**time 1.37s**

---

> > Optimal Speed, but missing required sorting of empty dates first

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
  id, daterun, datefirstprinted,
  case datefirstprinted when "0000-00-00 00:00:00" then 1 else 0 end as notprintedyet
FROM
  patientrecords
WHERE
  dateuploaded <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
ORDER BY                        
  datefirstprinted                                     /* not ordered properly */
LIMIT 10;
```

**time 0.48s**

---

> I tried using a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/views.html)

```
create view notprinted_patientrecords as (
   SELECT id, daterun, datefirstprinted, case datefirstprinted when "0000-00-00 00:00:00" then 1 else 0 end notprintedyet
   FROM patientrecords
   WHERE dateuploaded <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
);
```

*unfortunately when i run [explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html)*

```
 explain select * from notprinted_patientrecords order by notprintedyet desc limit 10;
```

*it shows that i am still using `filesort` and takes* **1.51s** *aka no savings at all*

---

> Would it be faster if datefirstprinted default is NULL?

*maybe, but in this legacy app that could do more harm than the 5 seconds extra in page load time*

---

> What else might we try? Stored procedures? Functions?

---

**UPDATES**

> As suggested @strawberry - ORDER BY CASE

```
...
ORDER BY                        
  case datefirstprinted when "0000-00-00 00:00:00" then 1 else 0 end, datefirstprinted
LIMIT 10;
```

**time 1.52s**

---

as requested by @e4c5, the `explain` output:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: patientrecords
         type: range
possible_keys: dateuploaded,uploads_report
          key: dateuploaded
      key_len: 5
          ref: NULL
         rows: 299095
        Extra: Using index condition; Using filesort
```

*except for **not ordered properly** which has the following variance*

```
        rows: 10
        Extra: Using where
```

*create table statement*

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Table: patientrecords
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `patientrecords` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `datecreated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `dateuploaded` datetime NOT NULL,
  `daterun` datetime NOT NULL,
  `datebilled` datetime NOT NULL,
  `datefirstprinted` datetime NOT NULL,
  `datelastprinted` datetime NOT NULL,
  `client` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `dateuploaded` (`dateuploaded`),
  KEY `daterun` (`daterun`),
  KEY `uploads_report` (`dateuploaded`,`client`),
  KEY `datefirstprinted` (`datefirstprinted`),
  KEY `datelastprinted` (`datelastprinted`)
)
```

Comment: You are trying to speed up a query that takes one or two milliseconds?  Just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @gordonlinoff - not sure why i put "ms" in the times...it is in seconds.  thx - updated.

Comment: Did you try ordering by `case...`

Comment: @strawberry i believe it is identical under the hood to simply doing `notprintedyet desc` since that operation has already taken place - i tested it and added the time.

Comment: please do share the explain outputs too

Comment: @e4c5 added `explain` output

Comment: one more thing. What are those indexes? Can you post the SHOW CREATE TABLE too. All this information is really needed to figure this out

Comment: @e4c5 added `create table` statement - i'm going to have to sign out and return to this in the a.m. thx for your interest in the question.

Comment: Is `limit 10` (or a low number) your usual use case? In this case you can optimize it more.

Comment: @solarflare this is clinical for the question.  the limit has to do with pagination. the actual query run will vary greatly given other search parameters and columns not included here.

Comment: Yes, I expected the limit to be for pagination. But as long as it is a low number in most cases (or as long as you in most cases just want to get/optimize e.g. the first 5 pages and don't care that much if page 100 is fast too), there are some ways to improve your query (which means: write it in a way to use an index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following ideas learned on concatenated indexes thanks to @e4c5, I tried adding a key on the two columns (column used in `where` and column used in `case` based `order` clause):

```
alter table
  patientrecords
add index
  printedvsuploaded (datefirstprinted, dateuploaded);
```

This initially had no effect since mysql continued to use the index `dateuploaded`.

However adding `force index` reduces the query time:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
  id, daterun, datefirstprinted
FROM
  patientrecords
FORCE INDEX (printedvsuploaded)
WHERE
  dateuploaded <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
ORDER BY
  case when datefirstprinted = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" then 1 else 0 end desc,
  datefirstprinted
LIMIT 10;
```

**time 0.64 seconds**

*it is worth noting that i agree with @e4c5 that the extra index will eventually cause writes to have a performance hit; i'm counting on other roadmap development to help with the reduction of the index count. for now, implementing this will reduce the 10 second page loads of the larger result sets to the manageable 3 second range and is then the solution that will be implemented.*

Comment: Have you tried using no index at all (e.g. with `ignoreindex` or by forcing the primary key)? The current index should not improve your query that much compared to the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your table, the first thing to note is that the following index is redundant

```
KEY `dateuploaded` (`dateuploaded`),
```

it's role can be fullfilled by this one

```
KEY `uploads_report` (`dateuploaded`,`client`),
```

So let's drop the `dateuploaded` key. It's not clear whether you actually use the client column in any queries. If you don't, I do believe changing your index as follows will give you a big speed up

```
KEY `uploads_report` (`dateuploaded`,`datefirstprinted`,`client`),
```

This is because mysql can only use one index per table. Since the index on the dateuploaded column is being used in the where clause, the index for the `datefirstprinted` cannot be used. But if you combine the two column into the same index it can be used in both the sort and the where.

After you have made the above index, this one could probably be dropped:

```
KEY `datefirstprinted` (`datefirstprinted`),
```

Having fewer indexes will make your inserts and updates faster.

Comment: Given that ["A concatenated index is one index across multiple columns...(and) a two-column index does not support searching on the second column alone"](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/concatenated-keys#sb-full-table-scan) this breaks dozens of other legacy queries in the application and appears to do nothing for the question at hand.

Comment: Take a note of this caveat: 'It's not clear whether you actually use the client column in any queries. If you don't, I do believe changing your index as follows will give you a big speed up'

Comment: Hmm...looking further into this, I think you brought me to a solution.  How should I present what worked since it is actually your post that brought me to it?  Shall I edit your post pointing out what worked for me in an update?

Comment: standard practice is to upvote the helpfull answer and post your own answer saying what actually worked and then to accept your own answer.